# RESTful Grails: how do I include related entities in my XML?

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

Let's say I have a class called Store that has many Employees. My RESTful listXML method looks like this:

```
def listXML = {
    render Store.list() as XML
}
```

And the result looks like this:

```
<stores>
  <store id="1">
   <name>My Store</name>
   <employees>
     <employee id="1" />
   </employees>
  </store>
</store>
```

My question is, how do I include all the data of each Employee class, so that my XML looks something like this?

```
   <stores>
      <store id="1">
       <name>My Store</name>
       <employees>
         <employee id="1">
           <name>John Smith</name>
           <hireDate>2008-01-01</hireDate>
         </employee>
       </employees>
      </store>
    </store>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller, you'll want to import the deep converter:

```
import grails.converters.deep.XML
```

You can read about it in the first couple of paragraphs of the [Converters Reference](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference).

Comment: Wow- thanks so much for the quickdraw answer. I'm so glad the solution was so easy!

Comment: Heh, no problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: I have a simple question here, should we really use deep converters and set it to default in config, doesn't it affect queries and response as it contains too much iformation on complete hierarchy ?

Answer (score 4):

As of Grails 1.1 you will be able to configure Grails to default to deeply serializing by including this in your grails-app/conf/Config.groovy:

```
grails.converters.xml.default.deep = true
```

1.1 also introduces named configurations for Converters. The deep converters will be deprecated and the named configuration "deep" should be used instead.

```
XML.use("deep") {
   render model as XML
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only allows for static configuration, which sometimes isn't optimal if you only sometimes need to render deep XML (and other times render shallow). There's a JIRA open on this (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5972), so after it's fixed, the solution for this issue may change again :).